# How can I change a tag in my HTML from the server?

Tags: node.js

I have a node.j server and I want to change my HTML when a post request is received with a certain value. It is a login function where I need some form of indicator when a login has failed.

I tried:

```
res.send("Login failed").redirect(homepage);
```

but of course, it doesn't work and crashes my server.

I want to send information to the client and redirecting the user back to the original page.

Here is the error when I try the mentioned row:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to         the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:467:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\TSN\1.0\Dev\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (D:\TSN\1.0\Dev\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:888:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (D:\TSN\1.0\Dev\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:926:18)
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\TSN\1.0\Dev\API\routes\Users\usersRouteHandler.js:83:38)
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\TSN\1.0\Dev\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:525:10)
    at Query._callback (D:\TSN\1.0\Dev\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:491:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (D:\TSN\1.0\Dev\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (D:\TSN\1.0\Dev\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (D:\TSN\1.0\Dev\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:123:8)
```

Comment: Can you include the error message you get when the server crashes?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
res.send(‘<div>text</div>’).redirect(‘/‘)
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality to see a community discussion about "Try this" answers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're trying to set headers on the response after it has already been sent (`res.redirect()` sets headers to redirect). This is impossible, as by the time `res.send()` finishes, the response has already been sent and you can't redirect anymore.

Try `res.render()` instead.

**EDIT**

You can pass some data to `res.render()` and then use it inside your page. If you're using a templating engine, you can conditionally render an error message inside your page.

For example, if user enters the wrong password,

You can do something like,

```
res.render('auth/loginPage', { showError: true, errorMessage: 'Login Failed' });
```

Then inside your page template, conditionally render an error if showError is true (remember that the properties of the second argument of res.render will be passed into your template while rendering).

```
<% if (showError) { %>
   <div class="user-message user-message--error"><%= errorMessage %></div>
<% } %>
```

This will show an error on the login page.

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: res.render().redirect? I'm not sure I understand what to do with it, even after reading the docs...

Comment: @MoltasDev What I'm saying is that the approach you're using is wrong. Sending some data and then redirecting is essentially useless. If you want to show an error message to the user, use something like connect-flash. Alternatively, you can use res.render (A simpler approach). I've updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: I have a bit of HTML. does that count as a template and will it work on my own HTML? Just to be sure.

Comment: Raw html doesn't count as a template. You've to use a templating engine like pug, ejs or handlebars if you want to inject values into your page at render. If you aren't using a templating engine, just create multiple html pages (with and without error messages) and render the error message one when there's an error.

Comment: That would have to use different endpoints which I would like to avoid. The idea of the system is to only have a single page with all data being given form the API. Essentially the frontend is just GUI to use the API. That's the idea at least. Is there any other way of doing it without a template engine?